# How to fix x-axis of Dot Plot given .dat file with no x-axis

Tags: graphics, data

I am trying to create a dotplot in the same format as the one below
[image: Example of Graph I want to Create]

but my .dat file gives me a list of the data with each datapoint contained in a list [image: Output from .dat file]

When I use the ListPlot[data] function, it gives me an incorrect plot, I am having trouble fixing the x-axis. How do I get it to show each data point one at a time from 0 to 512

[image: Plot from ListPlot]

Comment: Are you saying that the x-value should be just the index mod 512?

Comment: Yeah, so like the first value would be (1, 0.7159771270002675), second value would be (2,0.3062832599074649) till the final value. I don't know how to get the x-axis to increment by 1

Comment: `ListPlot[testData // Flatten]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
testData = Array[{RandomReal[{-1, 1}]} &, 2000];
indexedData = MapIndexed[Join[Mod[#2, 512], #1] &, testData];
ListPlot[indexedData]
```

[image]

Or if you want unique x values up to total number of datapoints:

```
testData = Array[{RandomReal[{-1, 1}]} &, 512];
indexedData = MapIndexed[Join[#2, #1] &, testData];
ListPlot[indexedData]
```

[image]

You could also just create the list of indices/x-values independently:

```
testData = Array[{RandomReal[{-1, 1}]} &, 512];
indexedData = Transpose[{Range@Length@testData, Flatten@testData}];
ListPlot[indexedData]
```

Comment: where do I input the .dat file in this code? I'm very sorry but I don't understand how to get the specific data I need to use into the testData variable.

Comment: I have 512 points of data that I want to plot in order starting from the first piece of data in the file to the last piece of data in the file. All I have is the y-axis value of the data and the x-axis value just needs to be 1 to 512 with 1 being the first data value, 2 being the second data value, 3 being the third data value. and so on.

Comment: I thought you had already executed `data = Import[...]`. Just substitute `data` for `testData`. If that doesn't work, then we'd need to see what the actual result of the Import was, and maybe the actual structure of the `.dat` file.

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked as intended.